# Alphanumeric to numeric in c ambiguity

Tags: c++, c

All,

functions which check and covert if a string is a numerical or not such as atol and atoi ...
I checked in c/c++ reference in atol description and it was written like this in the case of absence of any numeric in the string.

> no conversion is performed and zero is returned.

Obviously this may be an ambiguity if the string i passed is `"0"` so atol will returns a zero same as the precedent case.

As the function signature is int atoi() or long atol() the returned value might be an int or long so the returned value will match in all cases with a returned value of a real int.(i mean even though atoi returns a negative value for no-numeric string this returned value matches with the conversion of the string of this value it self) ambiguity persist

is it unsafe to check a string if it is a numeric or not using this functions?
what would be the good solution for this case?

Comment: atoi is unsafe and you should use strtol instead.

Comment: C or C++, there can only be one. Also, Boost has lexical casting, job done

Comment: same case for strtol it is an int long strtol it returns zero in a non numerical case

Comment: @Aymanadou: `strtol` also tells you which character made it "stumble". By analyzing it after the call you can tell what happened. With `atoi` you have no such information.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the premise of the question is correct. The C standard says(http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf): 7.20.1 Numeric conversion functions
1 The functions atof, atoi, atol, and atoll need not affect the value of the integer
expression errno on an error. If the value of the result cannot be represented, the
behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Aymanadou: "... even though atoi returns a negative value for no-numeric string..." - that's incorrect. `atoi` returns `0` for all errors.

Comment: what about isdigit? isalpha? or to make your own... it is simple

Comment: @AndreyT True but i said "even though" making the accent on the type of returned value as an int whitch is zero that matches as i mentionned with atoi("0") returned value

Comment: @neagoegab: That would be a waste of time, considering that the library already provides this functionality in through `strto...` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) or [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), they return the position of the first invalid character so you know if any conversion has take place.

Comment: same case for strtol it is an int long strtol it returns zero in a non numerical case

Comment: From [the documentation](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtol/): `If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first invalid
     character in *endptr.  If there were no digits at all, however, strtol()
     stores the original value of str in *endptr.  (Thus, if *str is not '\0'
     but **endptr is '\0' on return, the entire string was valid.)`

Answer (score 2):

```
(int)strtol()
```

You can pass a char * to verify conversion

Answer (score 2):

Functions from `ato...` group have virtually no meaningful practical uses. In order to perform this conversion or check whether an input string has correct format use functions from `strto...` group.

In addition to returning the converted actual value, functions from `strto...` group will tell you which character in the input string caused the conversion process to stop. Additionally these functions will set the global `errno` variable to `ERANGE` in case of overflow. By analyzing this additional data after the call you can tell exactly whether the conversion was successful.

Meanwhile, `ato...` functions provide no meaningful diagnostic features. They also trigger undefined behavior on overflow.

Comment: strto... group also returns an int value so ambiguity persist.
you may want to say that i should work on the end_pointer passed as parameter to know if a conversion is done?? plz add some detail if you can?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c++11 you could make use of stoi() located in < string >. it will throw an exception if the conversion fails:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 0):

It is neither safe nor unsafe. It simply doesn't do it. Whether that's "safe" depends on what you've already done to validate input. If you want validation as part of the conversion of text to value, `strtol` gives you more information.